# How to create a global variable for session and use it across test cases ( RobotFramework,REST API )

Tags: rest, python-requests, robotframework

Can someone let me know how to create a global session variable and that session variable should be used across keywords/testcases . I have tried the following way and getting error as ${itoc_session} not found.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           RequestsLibrary
Library           Collections


*** Keywords ***

Create session for server
    @{auth}=  Create List  admin  admin123
    Create Session    httpbin    https://host141.swlab.net:71/  auth=@{auth}
    Set Global Variable     ${itoc_session}      httpbin

Get Policy for Server
     ${resp}=  Get Request  ${itoc_session}      uri=/policies/
     Log     ${resp.status_code}
    :FOR   ${item}   in  @{resp.json()}
    \   Log  ${item}
    \   ${get_policy_id}=    Get Variable Value    ${item['id']}
    \   ${get_policy_name}=    Get Variable Value    ${item['name']}
    \   Log     ${get_policy_id},${get_policy_name}       
    Set Global Variable    ${policy_id}      ${get_policy_id}


Get Policy with policyID
    ${res}=   Get Request    ${itoc_session}     uri = /policies/${policy_id}
    Log   ${res}
    Log   ${res.json()['name']} , ${res.json()['extReference']}



*** Test case ***

get_policy_id 
    Get Policy for Server

get_policy_details
     Get Policy with policyID
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never call `Create session for server`, so the variable never gets set.

Comment: thanks for identifying the mistake.  `Get Policy with policyID
     Create session for server
 ${res}=   Get Request    ${itoc_session}     uri = /policies/${policy_id}
 Log   ${res}
 #Log   ${res.json()['name']}
`  .